# Magento cannot retrieve payment method error

Tags: php, magento

I get a **"Cannot Retrieve Payment Method"** error when trying to view orders in the magento backend.

We recently switched from payment service providers and removed the old extension.

I've updated the core_config_data and disabled the old module.

But still I get the error messages.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:43:"Cannot retrieve payment method instance";i:1;s:6336:"#0 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(83): Mage::throwException('Cannot retrieve pay...')
#1 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(119): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(50): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getInfoBlock(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#3 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->setPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#4 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_payment', true)
#7 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(112): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_payment')
#8 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(45): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getPaymentHtml()
#9 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/water/dom...')
#10 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#16 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/water/dom...')
#17 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#18 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#23 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#25 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#26 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/water/dom...')
#27 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#28 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#33 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#34 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#35 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#36 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#37 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#38 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#39 /home/water/domains/waterfiltersonline.nl/public_html/index.php(140): Mage::run('', 'store')
#40 {main}";s:3:"url";s:86:"/index.php/guapa/sales_order/view/order_id/46749 /key/40431ebb890e2f2408cbc808b574eaf2/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Would a solution be to just replace the old payment method in sales_flat_quote_payment - method column with the new payment service provider?

Answer (score 3):

Your orders still refer to the old payment method. You can either update the entries in `sales_flat_order_payment` or define the old instance in your new module. Both will achieve the same.

Comment: So basically run a query in MYSQL and update the entries to msp_ideal (the new instance). Would this do the trick?

Comment: And how do you define the old instance into the new module? Is there a specific file that should be edited? Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: @Feggel, there is a `Model` file that defines the payment method. You could just add this to your module and extends the other Model file (for the new instance)

If not, updating the database is by far the simplest. Just update the payment method field and that should be enough (don't forget to backup the table first, just in case!)